# How to match the string patterns in php

Tags: php

I have an array of strings

```
$x=array("Hello","How","You","iam","fine")
```

I tried to extract one string with pattern like this

```
$y=preg_grep ("/Hello(\w+)/", $x);

print_r($y);
```

I want to have multiple pattern search and return using only one `preg_grep` can anybody help me over.

Comment: echo your output in your question

Answer (score 2):

Regex quantifier `+` means `match 1 or more times`. String `Hello` doesn't fits, 'cause there're 0 symbols after `Hello`. Use `*` quantifier which means `match zero or more times`:

```
$x=array("Hello","How","You","iam","fine");
$y=preg_grep ("/Hello(\w*)/", $x);
print_r($y);
// outputs: Array ( [0] => Hello )
```

Comment: Exactly. It's searching for "Hello[word]" but there's no such thing in the array. They may also want to add a space before the \w group unless they're searching for Helloween

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, does it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like :

```
$y = preg_grep("/(PATTERN_1|PATTERN_2)/", $x);
```

May I ask why you don't want to use a loop over your patterns ?

Comment: "I want to have multiple pattern search and return using only one preg_grep can anybody help me over."
My answer perfectly matches the conditions of the author : one preg_grep, multiple pattern search and return.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<?php    
    $x=array("Hello","How","You","iam","fine");
    $y=preg_grep ("/H(\w*)|Y(\w*)/", $x);
    print_r($y);
?>
```